# How to get info about how many minutes/seconds a particular video been watched in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, metadata, youtube-data-api

I was struck with a problem which needs the total view time on a particular Youtube video.

I checked with the [Youtube-data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and it seems to offer the following statistics:

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": "xyz",
    "likeCount": "a",
    "dislikeCount": "b",
    "favoriteCount": "c",
    "commentCount": "d"
   }
```

I expect the API to give me the statistic on the total view time of a particular video of interest.

Comment: `viewtime`? do you refer to the `duration` of the video? if so, [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046571/4092887) about how you can get the duration of a given video.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, the info I wanted was the total view time on a particular video. How many minutes/seconds has the video been watched to be precise.

Comment: Jaysurya, you need to [edit] your question with the comment you provided. Comments are temporal. Unfortunately, As far as I know, YouTube API does NOT expose such information, but, you can keep searching (*I did read some questions asking the same as you*), but I don't remember read any answer about it (*havinf tried search in Google, though*). Good luck.